# how to read/write from/into a list of dictionary

Tags: vb.net

i want to know how to manipulate the data from a

```
Public ListD As New List(Of Dictionary(Of String, String))
```

meaning read/write. Can you help me please?

I've tried with

```
ListD.Add("string_as_key", var_as_value)
```

but it haven't worked

Thanks!

Comment: Know how to Loop will also be apreciated. Im trying : ListD.Add("string_as_key", var_as_value) and it doesn't works.

Comment: Sounds like you need to pick up a book on VB.NET programming. That's not something we can teach you in a couple of line answer on Stack Overflow.

Comment: i know how to manipulate data from a list and from a dictionary but, for some reason i can make them work together :S

Comment: What code have you tried already? Use the "edit" link to add that to your question. I wouldn't have said anything except for your comment where you asked for help on how to loop... :-)

Comment: Why do you need to use a `List` of a `Dictionary` - this is not usual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of

> ("string_as_key", var_as_value)

To add that to your ListD you would first have to either create a dictionary and add that item to it, or add that item to one of the existing dictionaries.

For example:

```
'Create dictionary
Dim dic as new Dictionary(Of String, String)
dic.Add("string_as_key", var_as_value)

'Add it to list
ListD.Add(dic)
```

To read a single item from your ListD would look something like:

```
Dim dic As Dictionary(Of String, String) = ListD(0)
Dim var_as_value As String = dic("string_as_key")
```

A dictionary is a group of multiple items in itself.  So if you have several pairs of things with unique items you can use as a key, a dictionary is a good choice.

I may be way off here since I don't know what you are using it for, but I get the impression that rather than a list of Dictionary you may be better of with just a dictionary(Of String, String)

Answer (score 0):

Your question can't really be 'answered' but to give you a start have a look at the online documentation, specifically:

[List(Of T) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST%601%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-VB%29&rd=true)

[Dictionary(Of TKey, TValue) Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx)

[How to loop in VB.NET](http://www.dotnetperls.com/for-vbnet) <- Start here and work upwards when you understand each one.